# Websphere 7 startup time in a clustered environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, cluster-computing

Is there an easy way to figure out when a websphere cluster was last started ( not a single node like in a ripple start, i need to figure out when the application was fully down)

I guess there are ways to implement that with writing each nodes startup time in a database and compare the times but maybe theres an easy way with an mbean for example?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least several approaches to address your issue, depending on the requirements. Try to write them down if you need more details about any of the solutions below.

## A separate process connecting to DMgr's JMX connector listening for JMX notifications

Notifications sent by Server MBeans are listed here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2FServer.html (see "Notifications inherited from MBean Stateful" section).

### Pros

- no need to modify the application
- no polling

### Cons

- if the DMgr is down, you won't receive any notifications
- if that extra process crashes (or wasn't started at all), you end up in a big gap in your data
- requires extra user account with "monitor" role

## Again, a separate process connecting to DMgr's JMX connector and querying servers' JVM's "stats" attribute.

The default PMI configuration in WAS will return "UpTime" statistics, which will tell you how long a specific server was running.

The JVM MBean is documented here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2FJVM.html

The statistic returned in "stat" attribute implements JVMStats interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/management/j2ee/statistics/JVMStats.html

### Pros

- no need to modify the application

### Cons

- if the DMgr is down, you won't receive any notifications
- polling
- requires extra user account with "monitor" role

## Extra component(s) in the application.

There are ways of registering application components so that WAS sends them startup/shutdown events.

### Pros

- no need to write any code against JMX API
- DMgr's availability put out of the equation

### Cons

- you must be able to rebuild (or at least repackage) the application; if you are not a member of development team or if you receive the app from third-party, this approach may not be suitable